# Equivalent way of using XMLHttepRequest.responseText to load new html, instead of window.location(url)?

Tags: javascript, html, http

Is is possible to use vanilla JavaScipt to reload current window with new html(Page 1) from XMLHttpRequest.reponseText, and make everthing exactly the same as window.location(url)?
The following codes I have tried after searching for relevant key words:

```js
// JS code imported by Page 0
Button.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (event) => {
        var HttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var URL = '/new_url';
        HttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (HttpRequest.readyState == 4 && HttpRequest.status == 200) {
                document.open();
                document.write(HttpRequest.responseText);
                document.close();
            }
        }
        HttpRequest.open('GET', URL, true);
        HttpRequest.send(null);
    }
)
```

behaves differently from method using window.location(url) in at least 2 ways:

1. the url does not change to new url.
2. after Page 1 is loaded, clicking browser's back button leads the page all the way back to history before Page 0, rather than restoring Page 0.

```js
Button.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (event) => {
        var URL = '/new_url';
        window.location = URL;
    }
)
```

Comment: "_make everthing exactly the same as window.location(url)_". No, that's not possible, navigation resets all the scripts, which is not possible when staying on the current location.

Comment: @Teemu sorry for the misleading expression. Here I mainly hope to make them behave unidentifiably viewing from user, which includes back button behaviour and url display.

Comment: Go look into the History API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API